# Command runs fine in terminal, but not when run as cron job

Tags: cron, cron-task, crontrigger

I am trying to run the following test command every minute with cron:

```
apachectl status | grep 'requests currently being processed' && 'date' >> /output.txt 2>&1
```

This would run `apachectl status` and if the output contains 'requests currently being processed', it would print the result of the command `date` to the file output.txt.

If I run this in the terminal as the root user, there is no issue. However, running it as a cronjob every minute (I've added it to `/var/spool/cron/root`) as follows:

```
*/1 * * * * apachectl status | grep 'requests currently being processed' && 'date' >> /output.txt 2>&1
```

Does nothing - the `output.txt` file never gets generated and the job never shows in the log at `/var/log/cron`. What might the issue be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the full path to the executable files, you may easily find it using `which` command, like `which apachectl` etc.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/sbin/apachectl status | /bin/grep 'requests currently being processed' && 'date' >> /output.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Maybe cron line will better to be `* * * * * /usr/sbin/apachectl status .....`

Comment: @RomeoNinov agree, but that was not the problem that should be fixed =)